# What is the preferred way to get the first element of a random-access Scala collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

There are 2 ways to get the first element of a random-access Scala collection (e.g. Vector):

1) head

```
myCollction.head
```

2) apply

```
myCollction(0)
```

From what I gathered (from Scala 2.10.4 sources)

- head first checks if the collection is empty and throws an exception before calling apply(0)

  ```
  override /*IterableLike*/ def head: A = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.head")
      apply(0)
  }
  ```
- apply first checks the bounds of the index and throws IndexOutOfBoundsException before getting the element

  ```
  def apply(index: Int): A = {
    val idx = checkRangeConvert(index)
    getElem(idx, idx ^ focus)
  }

  private def checkRangeConvert(index: Int) = {
    val idx = index + startIndex
    if (0 <= index && idx < endIndex)
      idx
    else
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index.toString)
  }
  ```

What is the preferred way ? (actual benefits / pitfalls, not personal preference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## use *.headOption*

Usually preferred way is (but it depends on the context)

```
myCollection.headOption
```

`.headOption` returns Option value where option is Some when head is present and it is none if the collection is empty.

Using headOption does not throw exception is the collection is empty hence you do not have any unexpected surprises.

Both `.head` and zero index throw exceptions when the underlying collection is empty.

*It also depends on the context, if you want to fail if head element is not present then `.head` is a good way to do that, but it many cases you want to provide an alternative if collection does not have any elements in it*

Answer (score 1):

I think the most idiomatic way to select the first element of any collection, including a random-access collection such as `Vector`, would be to use the `headOption` method which returns `None` in the case that an exception would be thrown. Benefits of this approach would be that the caller can pattern-match on `headOption` and respond appropriately.